# Swap text using jquery

Tags: jquery, webpack

I am new in using webpack. I wanted to be able to change the label of button on click from "NO" to "YES" and vice versa when the button itself is clicked. This is what I wanted to achieve: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_text

```
import $ from "jquery";

const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
rootApp.innerHTML = '<button>NO</button>';
```

Comment: You don't appear to be using jQuery after importing it, what exactly are you asking?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The example you linked doesn't use jQuery but you import it. Do you want to use jQuery? If not, why do you import it? And where is your JS that toggles something?

Comment: Apart from what others have mentioned about jquery, your answer is in the link you put in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it with jQuery, you can use [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

```js
$('#root').click(function() {
  var currentState = $(this).text();
  $(this).text((currentState == 'NO' ? 'YES' : 'NO'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="root">NO</button>
```